# Screenly OSE browser keyboard input disabled

Tags: input, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

Installed Screenly OSE on my raspberry. Everything works well, except one thing: I need to login to redash (website with charts) from my screenly raspberry, but when I try to input my login and password data from UZBL browser, which is pre-installed with screenly, keyboard input does not work. Interesting thing is that if I press "inspect element" and then try to input some data in UZBL developers console, its working fine.

Can somebody help me with enabling keyboard input in UZBL browser on my raspberry with screenly ose?

Comment: I'm the creator of Redash. In case we need to adjust something in our HTML to support Screenly/UZBL feel free to report this in our issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

y I'm the creator of Screenly. We have made some changes in regards to this. Try upgrading to the latest development release and let me know if that solves the issue:

`$ bash <(curl -sL https://www.screenlyapp.com/install-ose.sh)`